# I want to be able to add function to a python class dynamically, not knowing their names in advance

Tags: python, class, dynamic, methods, instance

Suppose I have a list of names.  I want to be able to add these as instance functions to a class instance dynamically.  I know about types.MethodType but I am a bit of a novice in getting from there to here.  Essentially what I want to do is:

```
class foo( object ):
     def __init__(self):
         pass

f = foo()
names = ["a","b","c"]
for name in names:
    add name() to f  # not sure what to do here
    # what I wanted added to instance "f" is this for each name:
    def name(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print( "My name is %s" % inspect.stack()[0][3]   )       
        print( "__called, args=%r, **kwargs=%r" % (args, kwargs) )

f.a() # ==> calls f.a()
f.b(1,2,3) # calls f.b(1,2,3 )and so on
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Why not just build a class to handle names?  If you really insist on doing this you might try creating an empty dictionary/list and then appending values dynamically like that (rather than trying to dynamically grow your class methods).  Can you provide the pragmatics for this - the context may provide some insight on possible solutions (or alternative techniques)?

Comment: This looks like a solution in search of a problem. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @burhan, nascent: short story is that I want to read a file in of parameter names from a file.  Using these names, I want the users of my class to be able to do something like "val=f.parameter()".  yes, yes, I could build a dict and have them do f.parms["name"], etc. but due to some perceived value on the customer's part, the f.parameter() idiom is what is wanted.  Sometime users ask for things that don't always make the most sense - ever seen a pink Cadillac driving around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create your functions as nested functions it's easier; `name` is then a variable taken from the nested scope:

```
import types
def buildMethod(name, instance):
    def namefunc(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "My name is %s" % name
        print "__called, args=%r, **kwargs=%r" % (args, kwargs)
    namefunc.__name__ = name
    setattr(instance, name, types.MethodType(namefunc, instance, type(instance)))

f = foo()
names = ["a","b","c"]
for name in names:
    buildMethod(name, f)
```

This results in:

```
>>> f.a
<bound method instance.a of <__main__.foo instance at 0x100d8e560>>
>>> f.a.__name__
'a'
>>> f.a()
My name is a
__called, args=(), **kwargs={}
>>> f.b()
My name is b
__called, args=(), **kwargs={}
>>> f.c()
My name is c
__called, args=(), **kwargs={}
```

Comment: +1, I had been working on something very similar but was getting hung up on trying to get `inspect.stack()[0][3]` to return the name.

Comment: @F.J. -- Me too.  I had decided that I needed a closure to get the name in there, I just hadn't thought of pulling the whole thing into another function to actually get the closing scope right.

Comment: Is `__name__` preferred to `func_name`, or is it a tomato/Tomato issue?

Comment: @mgilson: `__name__` is preferred, it's universal (try it on a built-in function, for example).

Comment: @Martijin - you have answered a bunch of my questions recently - thanks and you really know this stuff well!!

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong about `setattr` alone being sufficient. This works, though:

```
import inspect
import types

class foo( object ):
     def __init__(self):
         pass

def namefunc(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print( "My name is %s" % inspect.stack()[0][3]   )       
    print( "__called, args=%r, **kwargs=%r" % (args, kwargs) )

f = foo()
names = ["a","b","c"]
for name in names:
    setattr(f, name, types.MethodType(namefunc, f))

f.a() # ==> calls f.a()
f.b(1,2,3) # calls f.b(1,2,3 )and so on
```

Comment: The OP is missing a lot more than that.

Comment: how does that add the actual code for the newly added function?  I need to auto-generate the CODE for the new function too - remember the new function has no code behind it yet...

Comment: @staggart You kind of left that part out of the original question. :-)

Comment: But all functions will have name `namefunc`

Comment: @black_dragon No. `setattr`'s second argument, `name`, is the name of the attribute that `namefunc` will be bound to. If you doubt, run it and see.

Comment: @Martijin: part1: it will look very similar to what you have except the list of names will be read from a yaml file and when "nameFunc" gets called, it will call another method with it's name.  E.g., nameFunc does this: do_real_work( name).  The idea here is that I want to do some "real" work based on the name of the function (such as reading in an external file named "name" and using that to compute a result.

Comment: @Martijin: part2: Now, there are a lot of different ways to do that but the user has requested that s/he be able to do effectively this: value=f.a()  where "a" is not know until runtime (hence the dynamic add).  Yes, it's a bit strange, but this is what s/he wants.